# Backup / Transfer data to new computer

Tags: civilization-5

I am upgrading to a new computer with Windows 7 and would like to retain settings / saves and my hall of fame.

What folder locations should I backup and later restore?

Are there any gotchas?

Comment: OS of the old and new computer would help ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All user data is stored in `My Documents > My Games > Sid Meier's Civilization 5`. Copying this folder to the equivalent location on your new computer after installing the game will transfer your saves. You should double check everything has transferred correctly before getting rid of your old computer though!